# Micrisoft Access finds entries within 30 minutes of each other for each user ID everyday

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make a query that shows any entries that have been entered 30 minutes within each other from one ID. The form itself takes over 30 minutes to complete so I am trying to filter those that probably just whizzed through it and flag them.

For example, I would like it to flag this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASwFV.png)

I have a table that daily updates the following fields (for whenever a person inputs into an online form): 
EMP ID, date/Timestamp (day and time),  SbjNum/ form number, Case ID, and total.

I tried following:
[SQL Query for datetime within 5 minutes of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872846/sql-query-for-datetime-within-5-minutes-of-each-other)

but it seems to pull too many of the same sbjnum, thus making more than I want?

```
SELECT [QueDooblo].[EMP_ID] AS EMP_ID, [QueDooblo].[Date] AS [Date], [QueDooblo].[SbjNum] AS SbjNum, [QueDooblo].[R_ID] AS Case ID, [QueDooblo].[Total] AS Total
FROM (SELECT QueDooblo.[EMP_ID], QueDooblo.[Date], QueDooblo.[SbjNum], QueDooblo.[IncentiveAmount], QueDooblo.[SIGREFUSED_O1], QueDooblo.[R_ID], QueDooblo.[Total] FROM QueDooblo GROUP BY QueDooblo.[EMP_ID], QueDooblo.[Amount], QueDooblo.[Date], QueDooblo.[SbjNum], QueDooblo.[IncentiveAmount], QueDooblo.[SIGREFUSED_O1], QueDooblo.[R_ID], QueDooblo.[Total])  AS a
INNER JOIN QueDooblo AS b ON a.[EMP_ID] = b.[EMP_ID] 
WHERE (((DateDiff("n",[a].[Date],[b].[Date]))<30));
```

I tried to just do a regular JOIN but it wouldn't work... and add under Where `WHERE (((DateDiff("n",[a].[Date],[b].[Date]))<30) AND a.[SbjNum] <> b.[SbjNum] AND a.[EMP_ID] <> 0);`

What I am doing is just copying this data and putting into an Excel sheet and deleting duplicates then deleting any other repeated information

I also have another idea that perhaps I should just separate the date/Timestamp so that I could have Access only find if the EMP ID = EMP ID, and date is equal, but time is within each 30 minutes of each other?

Comment: *but it seems to pull too many of the same sbjnum* .. that's because you are running a many-to-many join and not one-to-one or one-to-many join. Since there are multiple `EMP_ID` and multiple `SbjNum` across multiple time stamps per day, you need to make a decision of which rows to compare rather than *all*. Do you want latest `EMP_ID` and `SbjNum` of last 30 minutes? Count the entries in last 30 minutes? Maybe back up and tell us your overall needs. What metric or statistic are you attempting to calculate? Show data to illustrate.

Comment: Dear Parfait, thank you for your response. I guess I want the database to show any entries that have been entered 30 minutes within each other from one Employee. The form itself takes over 30 minutes to complete so I am trying to filter those that probably just whizzed through it?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a correlated aggregate subquery to find last timestamp per `EMP_ID` and then use it to query from a subquery. Below returns all records less than 30 minutes from last by each employee:

```
SELECT  main.*,  DateDiff('n', main.last_date, main.[Date]) AS mins_elapsed
FROM 
     (SELECT q.*,
           (SELECT MAX(sub.[Date])
            FROM QueDooblo AS sub
            WHERE sub.[EMP_ID] = q.[EMP_ID]
              AND sub.[Date] < q.[Date]) AS last_date
      FROM QueDooblo q
    ) AS main
WHERE  DateDiff('n', main.last_date, main.[Date]) < 30
ORDER BY  main.EMP_ID, main.[Date];
```

If you do not expect employees to fill out form across midnight, add an equality on date using [`DateValue`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) in the correlated subquery.

```
...
     (SELECT q.*,
           (SELECT MAX(sub.[Date])
            FROM QueDooblo AS sub
            WHERE sub.[EMP_ID] = q.[EMP_ID]
              AND DATEVALUE(sub.[Date]) = DATEVALUE(q.[Date])
              AND sub.[Date] < q.[Date]) AS last_date
      FROM QueDooblo q
    ) AS main
```

**NOTE**: Correlated aggregate subqueries are expensive so will degrate performance on large tables. Maybe one day MS Access will support [window functions](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) (please upvote and share)? To help, consider building a temp table if using behind a form or report:

```
SELECT * INTO myTable FROM myQuery
```